# docker build error while copying source file to php container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up my symfony project in docker, and i'M struggling building the php container.
I've put all my source code in `\var\www\app\`
Here is an extract of my docker-compose.yml:

```
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '/var/www/app:/var/www'
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .env
    user: 1000:1000

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.0-alpine
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - '/var/www/app:/var/www'
      - './docker/nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:ro'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    depends_on:
      - php
```

here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM composer:2.0 as composer

FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN pecl install apcu

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y \
libzip-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-enable apcu

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY --chown=1000:1000 var/www/app /var/www

RUN PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/app/vendor/bin:bin

RUN composer install --no-scripts --prefer-dist \
  && rm -rf "$(composer config cache-dir)" "$(composer config data-dir)"
```

and here's the error I get while trying to build the php container:

```
Step 9/11 : COPY --chown=1000:1000 var/www/app /var/www
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder883740312/var/www/app: no such file or directory
```

The problem, I guess, is that it tries to fetch file within the docker build folder instead of `/var/www/app`. I thought it was because of the context, and I've tried to change it but then it cannot find my Dockerfile anymore.
I don't see how to resolve this, yyet I have the feeling it is a veryy easy one...But I'm quite lost at the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You try to COPY a folder at build time and then at runtime you replace the same by using a VOLUME in your docker-compose. Maybe the volume is not needed?

Regarding the error, docker expects your `var` folder to be at the same level as docker-compose.yml. If that is not the case and your `var` folder is in `docker/php/`, then that is what you have to set as context in your docker-compose.yml.

```
  php:
    build:
      context: docker/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

If the Dockerfile is in the context, you don't even need to declare it explicitly in the docker-compose.yml

Comment: well the dockerfile is in context, so your change did not solve the error. The problem is rather than  ```/var``` is not in context. About the volume, I need to to expose my source code and be able to modify in my editor and gets reported immediately in the container

Comment: did you even try my change? FYI: Dockerfile is not in the context. The path docker/php/Dockerfile is. This is a subtle but fundamental difference.

Comment: Yes I did, but I still get the exact same message

Comment: If you are trying to copy something from the host path /var/www/html then that will never work. As you correctly say, that is outside of the context. If this is what you are trying to do then the question is why do you have your source files in that location? Ideally the source files and the Dockerfile should be kept together.

Comment: Well, they are kept together. Source code is in ```/var/www/app``` and docker file is in ```/var/www/app/docker/php/```. This said, your comment gave me the idea to replace ```/var/www/app``` by ```./```. I don't know yet if it truly works since I got another error in a later step, but at least the COPY is not crashing anymore. Thanks for you moral support and hints!